# Need to add copy button to each cell of a column in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use ngx-clipboard module in my angular application.

The data in the table is coming from a service and i am using `jsonToTable()` to insert a dynamic table.

component.ts

```
generateOverrideCode(){

try {
    document.getElementById('tableGoesHere').innerHTML = this.jsonToTable(data, 'table table-sm table-dark');
  } 
catch (ex) {
  console.log('--generate override code', ex);  
}
}


capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

jsonToTable(json, classes){

var cols = Object.keys(json[0]);

var headerRow = '';
var bodyRows = '';

classes = classes || '';

cols.map((col)=>{
  headerRow += '<th>' + this.capitalizeFirstLetter(col) + '</th>';
});

json.map((row)=> {
  bodyRows += '<tr>';

  cols.map((colName)=> {
    if(colName != 'population')
    bodyRows += '<td>' + row[colName] + '</td>';
    else
    bodyRows += '<td id="colName+row">' + row[colName] + '<button></button>' + '</td>';  //I want to add a dynamic id to the button added to each cell of this row, so that i can use the id to target the text of that cell.
  });

  bodyRows += '</tr>';
});

return '<table class="' +
       classes +
       '"><thead><tr>' +
       headerRow +
       '</tr></thead><tbody>' +
       bodyRows +
       '</tbody></table>';
  }
 }
var data = [
{ country: 'China',         population: 1379510000 },
{ country: 'India',         population: 1330780000 },
{ country: 'United States', population:  324788000 },
{ country: 'Indonesia',     population:  260581000 },
{ country: 'Brazil',        population:  206855000 },
];
```

component.html

```
<div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-12">
                <button (click)="generateOverrideCode()">Generate</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tableGoesHere"></div>
```

What i am trying to achieve is adding a copy button next to the each cell in the third column.
[image]

I also want each cell to have a unique id so i can target it using ngx-clipboard directive. Follow link for example

https://maxisam.github.io/ngx-clipboard/

I have created a stackblitz example as well. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5g1b5

Please help me with adding unique id to each cell then i will move to adding ngx-clipboard.(i have added comments in stackblitz where i attempted to add unique id)

Comment: Please post the relevant "*[mcve]*" code *in* your question, don't just post it somewhere on the internet and expect us to go and look; make it *easy* for people to help you and you'll get more and better answers. How to post a Stack Snippet (in your question): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: I'm well aware you posted a link to your code; that's not what I was asking for: your code needs to be contained in the question itself (though a link to an external demo is appreciated as a bonus).

Comment: @DavidThomas I edited my question please have a look at it now